# The "Your flagging history" block uses the plural when the number of flags is 1

Tags: support, status-completed, profile-page, user-interface, plurals

The phrase should be "1 is waiting for review."

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Either flag another or don't flag in single units.

Comment: If, indeed, you want to use the numeral 1 at all.

Comment: Moderators should not review single flags. `:-)`

Comment: @Popular Demand: When would one not want to use the numeral `1`?

Comment: We've seen this type of bug opened many a time, but now we have an english.stackexchange.com I now find it ever-so ironic.

Comment: @Andrew, I've always been taught to not start sentences with numerals, or to use numerals at all for numbers smaller than (depending on who you ask) ten, twelve or twenty. Of course, these are just bulleted list items in not-super-formal writing, so those rules don't necessarily apply; I'd probably design this page the same way, if it were up to me. Regardless, it looks vaguely wrong to some part of my brain.

Comment: As it is a list, the text could also be "Waiting for review: 1." In the same way, the other text could be "Marked as valid: 16." (The period is not part of the text.)

Answer (score 11):

The content of the block has been changed, and it now appears as in the following screenshot.

[image: screenshot]

*Are* and *is* don't appear anymore in the used strings.